# How can I tell from the equation $x^3+y^3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ that it is an unbounded set of values

Tags: compactness

$x^3+y^3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is according to my textbook not bounded since, for each $x_0 \in R$ there is a $y_0$ such that the point $(x,y_0)$ is on the curve.

Isn't that true for a bounded set also e.g $x^2+y^2=1$. Im not sure what this statement says exactly.

Comment: No take $x=10$. There does not exist a $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $100+y^2=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that is not true, the difference between these 2 cases is that equation $y^3=a$ will have a real solution for any $a$, but $y^2=a$ will have a solution only for $a\geq0$, so if $|x|>1$ you will not find such $y_0$

Comment: got it! Also I am wondering how you can tell that x^3+y^2=1/sqrt(3) has points inside the circle that is all points such that:  x^2+y^2 =< 1.

Comment: @FWi Just consider some values of $-1\leq x\leq 1$ and plug them into $x^3 +y^3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ after that check will your point be in a unit circle. For example, you can take $x=0$